# Java stream filter with element in a constant tab

Tags: java-stream

I have two class like this :

```
public class Forecast {
    private List<Element> elements;
    private Person person;
}
```

```
public class Element {
    private String element;
}
```

I have a constant of String[] like this :
`private static final String[] ELE = {"element1", "element2", "element3"};`

I would like to retrieve all the elements of my list in forecast which contains one of the elements of my constant with Stream.

So, I started by doing this to test :

```
public List<Element> getElement(String person) {
    return getElement(person).getList()
            .stream()
            .filter(r  -> r.get(0).getElement.equals("element1"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Now I would like to use my constant ELE, and I don't find how to go through it and test my elements

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
private static final List<String> ELE_LIST = java.util.Arrays.asList(ELE);

public List<Element> getElement(String person) {
    return getElement(person).getList()
            .stream()
            .filter(r -> ELE_LIST.contains(r.get(0).getElement()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```